# In Java - need to sum elements of an array when two are the same

Tags: java

I am trying to code in Java and I am very much a beginner. I do not know who to get started with my issue. I need to look at eight different Source codes and if they match then add the two values together. For example: (the pattern repeats eight times)

```
SrcContrib1 = A
SrcContribAmt1 = 2,000.00

SrcContrib2 = J
SrcContribAmt2 = 3,000.00

SrcContrib3 = D
SrcContribAmt3 = 400.00

SrcContrib4 = A
SrcContribAmt4 = 1,000.00
```

For SrcContrib = A ; I need one result = 3,000.00

I hope this is enough information. If not let me know. 
Thank You

Comment: Source codes? Did you mean - variables?

Comment: This is not enough information. How is the data stored?

Comment: Use a map to store the results (e.g. `Map<String, Double>`), get the value for a key, add the new value or create one and put it back to the map.

Comment: It will be helpful if you give an example with input and expected output.

Comment: I guess you best start by showing the code that you wrote so far; and precisely documenting where you are stuck.

Comment: I apologize, when I said Source Codes, that is what the name of my data. Not meant to represent anything to do with the coding. For example - we use 13 different 'Source Codes' to represent what type of contribution to apply. I am using CloverETL. The data is stored in a flat file. I am not sure if anyone is familiar with CloverETL but I am building a graph that results in a single output of all 'Source Codes' and the amount. If not I may not be able to explain it enough to get an answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should use the Map for it. Try This code

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

     public static void main(String []args){
        double oldValue = 0.00;
        Map<String,Double> map = new HashMap();

        add(map,"A",2000.00);
        add(map,"J",3000.00);
        add(map,"D",400.00);
        add(map,"A",1000.00);
        for (String key : map.keySet()) {
              System.out.println(key + " " + map.get(key));
} 

     }
     public static void add(Map<String,Double> map,String key,double value){
         double oldValue = 0.00;
        if(map.get(key) == null)
           map.put(key,value); 
        else{
           oldValue = map.get(key);
           map.put(key,value+oldValue ); 
        }

     }
}
```